# Strange Rep Count

Tags: support

So today I noticed that one of my answers had gained a strange amount of rep (+17). I checked it out in my profile, and saw that it had gained 15 points from being accepted and another 2 from being upvoted.

Now, I've never seen any scenario where one of my answers gets accepted and upvoted, but the upvote only counts for +2 rep. What is this? (Sorry for any incoherence, I'm pretty tired.)

Screenshot of rep counter thingy:

[image: Rep]

Link to Q&A: [Ubuntu 15.10 root account login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731331/ubuntu-15-10-root-account-login/731354)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hit your [daily reputation limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/270345):

[image]

You got a +2 from an upvote to since there was a -2 from a downvote. If something will take you over the reputation limit, then only as much reputation to get you to the limit is granted from it.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks